# How to re enable the disabled google map v3 drag,drop,zoom etc

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Upon opening an infowindow I set:

```
map.setOptions({draggable: false, zoomControl: false, scrollwheel: false, disableDoubleClickZoom: true});
```

This allows user to not able to interact with the map any longer, but when user click on "close" on the infowindow... how do I set it back to default?

Comment: add a listener to the close click event and do that?  Although there are other ways to close an infowindow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe the `map_changed`-event of the infowindow, this event will fire each time when the infowindow will be opened or closed(no matter how this will be triggered).

Set the values depending on the map-property of the infowindow(it's `null` when it's closed, otherwise a Map-instance)

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      zoom: 14,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.549878, 13.425209),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }),
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: map.getCenter()
    }),
    win = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: 'hello world'
    });

  google.maps.event.addListener(win, 'map_changed', function() {
    
    //will be true when infowindow is open
    var boo = !!this.getMap();
    
    map.setOptions({
      draggable: !boo,
      disableDefaultUI: boo,
      scrollwheel: !boo,
      disableDoubleClickZoom: boo
    });
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    win.open(map, this);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off geocodeship comment
you can check if [close()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#close) was called when user colsed infowindow. If true then `map.setOptions({draggable: true...`.